# Blender Python module import

Tags: python, model, import, blender

At Blender I can use Python to develop a game...
But can I also use Blender in Python?
Is it possible to import Blender into a Python script? Here I made an overview:

```
Python -> 
    Blender -> 
        import Models -> create the game
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes that is possible.

First you need to compile blender from source yourself - see [the blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/Building_Blender) and this little bit of [information here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aIdeasman42/BlenderAsPyModule)

Basically when you first setup the configuration for building blender there is an option called `WITH_PYTHON_MODULE` which is described as `Enable building as a python module which runs without a user interface, like running regular blender in background mode (experimental, only enable for development)`

If building using cmake this option is listed under Advanced options so you need to enable advanced options to see it. Not certain if scons has a similar option.

This appears mostly undocumented, but sounds like you import bpy and have access to what you would normally use in a blender script just with the limitations of not having a gui.

Comment: take also one look at https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_61_release/info_tips_and_tricks.html Bundled Python & Extensions and Blender as a module.

Answer (score 1):

This package [link](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/mathutils.html) is a module which gives you access to Blender colors, objects etc

Just have a look!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is not possible,
Many softwares and platforms support for python and they have their own implementation which are completely isolated.
However I liked what @sambler proposed however doing that you have to be familiar with Blender source codes which is in C and I bet if someone could extract Blender's python object outside the project will do the rest in C not python, Theoretically you are able to do that but actually it is not a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old Blender 2.79  to develope a game in the game engine. Or you go to the fork of the Blender Game Engine: https://upbge.org.
Another solution is the Armory Project: https://armory3d.org which integrated their engine capabilities into Blender.

And yes you can built Blender as a python module: [Blender as Python Module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule)
If you want to dig deep into the topic, you might be interested in Tensorflow or Torch. Tensorflow is a neural network. If you want to build a game in 3 clicks, you first need to integrate the game development process into a Tensorflow or Torch model.

[Torch-Project-Website](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html)
[Tensorflow-Project-Website](https://www.tensorflow.org/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know concretely I just know that you can import 3D-models with the fileending .obj into pygame with this script:

[script](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader)

Comment: But like i said I'm not sure if it possible to import it directly into Python, the Blender module i mean...